# "@font-face declaration doesn't follow the fontspring bulletproof syntax" error when trying to implement custom font

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a custom font to my website, but keep getting the same error no matter what I try, and I can't find much about how to go about fixing it.

Here's my code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Moderna";
  src: url("/MODERNA.TTF")
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using something more than just vanilla HTML and CSS? Please put up a snippet which shows the context. And in particular read up about fontspring bullet proofing - this seems to require two src declarations (at least, it did for historic reasons).

Answer (score 0):

`The fontspring bulletproof syntax` is just a recommendation. It declares your `@font-face` must satisfy below syntax to work properly in most cases:

```css
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
        src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg')
    }
```

Most browsers supports TTF fonts now but if you can't see the font in browser try this

```css
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Moderna";
      src: url("/MODERNA.TTF") format("ttf");
    }
```

And if my memory serves me then the rule must be on top of your css file. And please check the file `/MODERNA.TTF` exists.

Comment: Tried it, it returns the same error.
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2KEIs9d

Comment: @MOODSINTOSH note please in your post that you face the error in a code editor

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your path/url is causing this issue:

```
  src: url("/MODERNA.TTF")
```

implies you're entering a direcory named 'MODERNA.TTF' and not a file.

As @Mik pointed out the recommended declaration should be fine – unless your file couldn't be found.
Depending on your html/css file structure it should rather be something like this:
(granted your font file resides in the same directory as your css.

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Moderna';
        src: url('MODERNA.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('MODERNA.woff') format('woff2'),
         url('MODERNA.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('MODERNA.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('MODERNA.svg#svgFontName') format('svg')
    }
```

Keep also in mind, that referencing font files via @font-face is **case-sensitive** (there might be exceptions).
So double check if your exact font file name is really using uppercase letters (MODERNA.TTF or moderna.ttf).